# How to find a duplicate class on the class path?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

How do I find a duplicate class on the class path?

Background:

I suspect to have a duplicate class (javax.mail.Session). I found one jar with this class, but I have no idea where the second jar containing the same class is.

I am using Eclipse.

Comment: Ask Eclipse to tell you. It should know what the source of the second class is.

Comment: If you are on maven, there's a [plugin that does that check](http://www.programmers-pain.de/2011/02/28/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin-find-duplicate-classes-in-maven-artefacts).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In eclipse press ctrl-shift-T and type Session:

[image: eclipse screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

These tools may be able to solve your problem:

1. [Classpath Inspector](http://alumnus.caltech.edu/%7Eleif/opensource/cpcheck/index.html)
2. [Classpath Checker](http://classpathchecker.free.fr/)

Answer (score 1):

Verify if this can help you. This script will find all jar files in a folder, extract all classes and find equal classes (exact same full name).

[Remove duplicate jars in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555928/remove-duplicate-jars-in-a-directroy/20611435#20611435)