# Appium Android driver error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, appium

I'm new at Appium Android Driver and I'm getting below error message while running my script.

Below is my script:

```
private static AndroidDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "Com_first_app/app/release");
    File app = new File(appDir, "app-release.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    //capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 6");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "");
    capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", false);
    capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("app-Package", "com.example.com_first_app");
    capabilities.setCapability("app-Activity", "com.example.com_first_app.Login");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElementById("com.example.com_first_app:id/email_sign_in_button").sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
    driver.findElementById("com.example.com_first_app:id/password").sendKeys("12345678");
    driver.findElementById("com.example.com_first_app:id/email_sign_in_button").click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.quit();
}
```

I get the Error message below while running the script above:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
>       at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:146)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:71)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:288)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.(ApacheHttpClient.java:259)
>       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:52)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:169)
>       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:82)
>       at com.example.com_first_app.appium_login.main(appium_login.java:28)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)``
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Have you looked at [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120188/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance-exception-is-thrown-by-appium-driver-varria)? Its answer might help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE exception is thrown by appium driver varriable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120188/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance-exception-is-thrown-by-appium-driver-varria)