# org.testng.TestNGException while trying to access PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng, apache-httpclient-4.x, pooling

So I have recently started facing `TestNGException` while trying to run our existing test suite using the IDE. By recently I mean updating the intelliJ and dependencies to try working on latest versions. The code and the stack-trace for failure is as follows -

**Code Usage**

***ITests.java*** -

```
public class ITests extends BaseTest {
    private final Action action = new Action();
}
```

***BaseTest*** (just to share the syntax)-

```
public class BaseTest {
    // where in this class does not use any instance of Http
}
```

***Action.java*** -

```
public class Action {
    private final Http http = Http.getInstance();
}
```

***Http.java*** -

```
public class Http {

    private static final Http INSTANCE = new Http(); //line 36

    public static Http getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private Http() {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(); //line 43
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100);
        RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(60000)
                .setConnectTimeout(60000)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(60000)
                .build();
        this.client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig)
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();
    }
}
```

***Maven Dependency*** -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

***StackTrace*** -

> ```
> org.testng.TestNGException: 
> Cannot instantiate class com.package.tests.test.ITests
>   at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
>   at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:382)
>   at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:295)
>   at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:118)
>   at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:183)
>   at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:128)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:416)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:242)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:212)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:159)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:549)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:161)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:114)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1290)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1277)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1131)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
>   at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
>   at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:122)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>   at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
>   ... 18 more
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool.setValidateAfterInactivity(I)V
>   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:176)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:158)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:149)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:125)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:116)
>   at com.package.core.Http.<init>(Http.java:43)
>   at com.package.core.Http.<clinit>(Http.java:36)
>   at com.package.tests.action.Action.<init>(Action.java:16)
>   at com.package.tests.test.ITests.<init>(ITests.java:24)
>   ... 23 more
> ```

***Note*** - Our project is base on maven, so while I execute the tests using `maven exec:java` the execution goes fine.

Please do ask for any other info required.

***Edit 1 -***

As asked by @hunter, debugging to get the exact path of `Cpool` from where it loaded. Evaluated -

```
Class.forName("org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool").getResource‌​("CPool.class")
```

Result -

> file:/Users/xyz/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar!/org/apache/http/impl/conn/CPool.class

***Edit 2 -***

`mvn dependency:tree` [most related to httpcomponents] -

--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree

> > com.package:core:jar:1.1.3

```
+- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
+- com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0:compile
+- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
+- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
+- org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile \- org.testng:testng:jar:6.9.9:compile
```

> > com.package:test:jar:1.1.3

```
+- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:6.0.3:compile
+- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
+- com.package:mobile:jar:3.6.2:compile |  +- com.pkg.serviceproxy:http-handler:jar:1.7.41:compile |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.3:compile |  +- com.pkg:bullseye-model:jar:1.2.0:compile |  |  +- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-httpclient:jar:3.0.2:compile |  +- kpg:pz-api:jar:0.2.38:compile |  |  \- com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:jar:1.4.7:compile |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.0.2:compile |  |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.6:compile
+- com.package:core:jar:1.1.3:compile
```

> > com.package:driver:jar:1.1.3

```
\- com.package:test:jar:1.1.3:compile
```

***Edit 3 -***
     intelliJ IDEA - 15.0.3 [Community] - updated on 19th Jan,2016

***Edit 4 -***

Bending more towards intelliJ, sharing the logs post running the tests using `testng.xml -> right click -> run`

```
> objc[21590]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> and
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib.
> One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
> [AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] error can't determine annotations of missing
> type javax.cache.annotation.CachePut when weaving type
> com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain when weaving classes 
> when weaving   [Xlint:cantFindType] [AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] error
> can't determine annotations of missing type
> javax.cache.annotation.CacheResult when weaving type
> com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain when weaving classes 
> when weaving   [Xlint:cantFindType] [AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] error
> can't determine annotations of missing type
> javax.cache.annotation.CacheRemove when weaving type
> com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain when weaving classes 
> when weaving   [Xlint:cantFindType] [AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] error
> can't determine annotations of missing type
> javax.cache.annotation.CacheRemoveAll when weaving type
> com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain when weaving classes 
> when weaving   [Xlint:cantFindType]
```

Comment: debug the test and put a break point first line Http constructor, and when break point hits evaluate this expression Class.forName("org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool").getResource("CPool.class")

Comment: @hunter - did that, what are we trying to achieve with that(read - what info is reqd. post that?)

Comment: it will display where the class Cpool has been loaded from, normally it should be from your local maven repo.but we can verify weather idea run-time refers to the correct jar . it should display a path, pls update the post with that result

Comment: @hunter - updated the post, the class is from my m2 only. detailed path in the post

Comment: tro try to evaluate following expression, Class.forName("org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool").getResource("AbstractConnPool.class")  , if it displays a httpcore version less than 4.4 , then it is incompatible with   httpclient 4.2.5 . it might be a dependency reolving problem in IDEA maven plugin.

Comment: Could you share the result of `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @JulienHerr any specific dependency(ies) you are interested in?

Comment: dependency tree will not help because this works in mvn command line , right?

Comment: @hunter - evaluates to `null`..
dependency versions and resolutions is what Julien might be worried about I guess

Comment: I didn't catch it is working well outside the ide.

Comment: it should not be null, something might be wrong in the expression i have given, anyway i am sure that this setValidateAfterInactivity method was introduced after version 4.4 of httpcore artifact, IDEA resolve a lower version of httpcore due to some reason,pls try what i mentioned in my answer

Comment: In fact, I'm pretty sure it is a classpath issue where idea and maven don't manage the order of the classpath in the same way.

Comment: @JulienHerr - updated the post with relative httpcomponents from all the packages used. Do call out in case of any specific suspicion.

Comment: `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile` looks bad! Just try to remove it from our dependencies.

Comment: @JulienHerr that is coming from `httpcomponents:httpclient 4.5.2` itself

Comment: True... You can try something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/11577079/4234729

Comment: @JulienHerr - tried using http://www.programmers-pain.de/2011/02/28/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin-find-duplicate-classes-in-maven-artefacts/ ... but no build errors, meaning no duplicate classes either

Comment: No more idea on my side. Are you able to share a minimal project which shows the issue ?

Comment: @JulienHerr - apologies, that wouldn't be feasible on my end either.

Comment: @JulienHerr - a final look at Edit 4, might help us maybe.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help, sorry. Did you try on another computer/os? As it looks like an idea issue, you should open an issue on it. But they will have to reproduce too and it is headache without a runnable project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IDEA, **Maven project tab**, click on the **Show dependencies** button (it will show a diagram) , then press `Ctrl+ F` in that diagram and type `httpcore` and check the version. if it shows the version less than 4.4 , you can analyze how dependencies has been resolved. Based on that you can adjust the `pom` to rectify the dependencies. Since it is working with `mvn` in the command line, this might be a incorrect behavior of the that IDEA resolve maven dependencies through its maven plugin.

Comment: `+- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
   |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile` from the tree

Comment: this versions are compatible, is this the output from mvn dependency:tree or output from IDEA dependency diagram? we cannot troubleshoot this using mvn dependency:tree

Comment: in IDEA hit Ctrl+N , then type AbstractConnPool browse to the class, now it will show you what is the jar that IDEA referes (in the Window titile)

Comment: sorry but this isn't helping

Comment: have you checked the versions in idea dependency diagram?

Comment: its shared in the post as well

Comment: no, i think you have shared the mvn dependency:tree, select the maven project in idea (in IDEA maven tab) and hot ctrl+shift+alt+U, this will generate the diagrame, lookup for the artifacts and its versions

Comment: just a suggestion, not everyone uses the same IDE/settings as yours, please look for better generalised steps while you direct to some settings.

Comment: same goes for the answer as well