# What is the cause for this SecurityException when I try to include the expectations for a mock obejct?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, expectations

I'm trying to use mock objects in my testing. However the same exception is being thrown when I try to list the expectations of the mock object.
The following is the stack trace of the exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.jmock.internal.InvocationExpectationBuilder.createExpectationFrom(InvocationExpectationBuilder.java:86)
    at org.jmock.internal.InvocationToExpectationTranslator.invoke(InvocationToExpectationTranslator.java:19)
    at org.jmock.internal.FakeObjectMethods.invoke(FakeObjectMethods.java:38)
    at org.jmock.lib.legacy.ClassImposteriser$4.invoke(ClassImposteriser.java:137)
    at com.activityrecommender.feeds.WeatherFeedBBC$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b8b5b5a8.refreshFeedData(<generated>)
    at com.activityrecommender.gui.BackgroundTest$2.<init>(BackgroundTest.java:39)
    at com.activityrecommender.gui.BackgroundTest.testBackgroundSunny(BackgroundTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The error is occurs when the following piece of code is executed:

```
context.checking(new Expectations() {{
            oneOf (feed).refreshFeedData();
        }});
```

What is the cause of this exception?

Comment: error message -> google -> answer(s) on stackoverflow -> [Java SecurityException : signer information does not match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match) (.. sorry)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error means that you're are trying to use classes (Hamcrest) which are potentially incompatible.

This is probably due to you having two instances of the [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) libraries in your build path. JMock depends upon Hamcrest, and JUnit uses and includes some Hamcrest classes in it's jar, so this is probably where the problem comes from.

The easiest fix is to use the version of JUnit which doesn't have the Hamcrest libraries included, [junit-dep](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjunit%7Cjunit-dep%7C4.10%7Cjar). This should make the problems go away. JUnit 4.x depends upon Hamcrest 1.1.