# How to assert greater than using JUnit Assert?

Tags: java, junit

I have these values coming from a test

```
previousTokenValues[1] = "1378994409108"
currentTokenValues[1] = "1378994416509"
```

and I try

```
    // current timestamp is greater
    assertTrue(Long.parseLong(previousTokenValues[1]) > Long.parseLong(currentTokenValues[1]));
```

I get the `java.lang.AssertionError` and `detailMessage` on debugging is `null`.

How can I assert greater than conditions in using `JUnit`

Comment: Post the entire code as well with the complete error message. Perhaps you're assertion statement is before the array initialization.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Just how you've done it. `assertTrue(boolean)` also has an overload [`assertTrue(String, boolean)`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) where the `String` is the message in case of failure; you can use that if you want to print that such-and-such wasn't greater than so-and-so.

You could also add `hamcrest-all` as a dependency to use matchers. See https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

assertThat("timestamp",
           Long.parseLong(previousTokenValues[1]),
           greaterThan(Long.parseLong(currentTokenValues[1])));
```

That gives an error like:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: timestamp
Expected: a value greater than <456L>
     but: <123L> was less than <456L>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the Hamcrest solution. I hate it when tests output `expected true got false` when the test is comparing integer values.

Comment: FYI, here is the link to `OrderingComparison` which contains `greaterThan`: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/number/OrderingComparison.html

Comment: `<groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>`, `<artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>`

Comment: Note that Hamcrest is included by default when you use JUnit 4.11 so no need to search for the dependency.

Comment: Be careful with the [order of hamcrest and junit references](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9659820/4794).

Comment: @Chanoch I think you need hamcrest-all to get Matchers.  JUnit only pulls in hamcrest-core which doesn't have greaterThan.

Comment: @yshavit , I recevie a slightly different error when I run this code.  `java.lang.AssertionError: timestamp
    Expected: a value greater than <456L>
         got: <123L>
         but: <123L> was less than <456L>`.  Which version of java are you using?

Comment: @Eric This was a couple years ago, but I probably had it on Java 6. I don't think that's the main factor, though; the version of Hamstring (and possibly JUnit?) is probably more relevant. And I'm not sure which of those I was using.

Comment: @AnthonyHayward I think this was in 4.10 though - I tested this out at the time and it worked for me. Doing a quick search now, there are a number of articles from the time talking about the complex dependencies with the junit-dep and hamcrest-library libraries which all seem to have been resolved by 4.11.

Comment: @Chanoch I have junit 4.12 which transitively depends on hamcrest-core 1.3.  There is no greaterThan method on org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers class.  If I add hamcrest-all 1.3 as an additional dependency, it provides org.hamcrest.Matchers.greaterThan method.

Comment: I had to use `import static org.hamcrest.number.OrderingComparison.*` so that it works.

Answer (score 30):

When using JUnit asserts, I always make the message nice and clear. It saves huge amounts of time debugging.  Doing it this way avoids having to add a added dependency on hamcrest Matchers.

```
previousTokenValues[1] = "1378994409108";
currentTokenValues[1] = "1378994416509";

Long prev = Long.parseLong(previousTokenValues[1]);
Long curr = Long.parseLong(currentTokenValues[1]);
assertTrue("Previous (" + prev + ") should be greater than current (" + curr + ")", prev > curr);
```

Comment: Nice solution, really clean.

Answer (score 18):

you can also try below simple soln:

```
previousTokenValues[1] = "1378994409108";
currentTokenValues[1] = "1378994416509";

Long prev = Long.parseLong(previousTokenValues[1]);
Long curr = Long.parseLong(currentTokenValues[1]);

Assert.assertTrue(prev  > curr );
```

Answer (score 12):

You should add Hamcrest-library to your Build Path. It contains the needed Matchers.class which has the lessThan() method.

Dependency as below.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

As I recognize, at the moment, in JUnit, the syntax is like this:

```
AssertTrue(Long.parseLong(previousTokenValues[1]) > Long.parseLong(currentTokenValues[1]), "your fail message ");
```

Means that, the condition is in front of the message.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively if adding extra library such as `hamcrest` is not desirable, the logic can be implemented as utility method using `junit` dependency only:

```
public static void assertGreaterThan(int greater, int lesser) {
    assertGreaterThan(greater, lesser, null);
}

public static void assertGreaterThan(int greater, int lesser, String message) {
    if (greater <= lesser) {
        fail((StringUtils.isNotBlank(message) ? message + " ==> " : "") +
                "Expected: a value greater than <" + lesser + ">\n" +
                "But <" + greater + "> was " + (greater == lesser ? "equal to" : "less than") + " <" + lesser + ">");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
assertTrue("your message", previousTokenValues[1].compareTo(currentTokenValues[1]) > 0)
```

this passes for previous > current values

Answer (score 0):

You can put it like this

```
  assertTrue("your fail message ",Long.parseLong(previousTokenValues[1]) > Long.parseLong(currentTokenValues[1]));
```