# Dataflow unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to build a unit test for my pipeline.

This pipeline read from pubsub, perform a transformation and write the result to pubsub again.

To simplify even more the unit test until it works, the unit test will only receive a string as an input and test if the output is the some string.

The code looks like the following:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class TesterPipeline {   

    // Our static output data, which is the expected data that the final PCollection must match.
    static final String[] COUNTS_ARRAY = new String[] {"this"};

    @Rule public TestPipeline p = TestPipeline.create();

    // Example test that tests the pipeline's transforms.
    @Test
    @Category(ValidatesRunner.class)
    public void testPipeline() throws Exception {

      // Run the pipeline.
      PCollection<String> input= p.apply("input string", Create.of("This is just a message").withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()));
      PAssert.that(input).containsInAnyOrder(COUNTS_ARRAY);
      p.run();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to execute the unit test using Eclipse but I got the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: input string/Read(CreateSource).out: class "org.hamcrest.Matchers"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert$PAssertionSite.capture(PAssert.java:169)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert.that(PAssert.java:411)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert.that(PAssert.java:403)
    at com.xxx.pipeline.TesterPipeline.testPipeline(TesterPipeline.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.TestPipeline$1.evaluate(TestPipeline.java:319)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.hamcrest.Matchers"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:891)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:661)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:754)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert$AssertContainsInAnyOrder.apply(PAssert.java:1497)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert$AssertContainsInAnyOrder.apply(PAssert.java:1476)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert$CheckRelationAgainstExpected.apply(PAssert.java:1146)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert$CheckRelationAgainstExpected.apply(PAssert.java:1126)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert.doChecks(PAssert.java:1425)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert$GroupedValuesCheckerDoFn.processElement(PAssert.java:1392)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert$GroupedValuesCheckerDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SimplePushbackSideInputDoFnRunner.processElementInReadyWindows(SimplePushbackSideInputDoFnRunner.java:78)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluator.processElement(ParDoEvaluator.java:216)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DoFnLifecycleManagerRemovingTransformEvaluator.processElement(DoFnLifecycleManagerRemovingTransformEvaluator.java:54)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.processElements(DirectTransformExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.run(DirectTransformExecutor.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Looking for some information about this error I found this to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651784/hamcrest-tests-always-fail) related. In her, the solution was:`The hamcrest.jar needs to go before the Junit library in the build path.`

I'm not sure If I have something wrong in my configuration, because I thought I had doe what that solution said, but I'm still get the same error.

Like I'm new with Java and also Eclipse maybe I'm executing wrong the unit test, but I did not find more information in the official  [doc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/test-your-pipeline/) of apache beam and neither in google [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/testing-your-pipeline)

The Junit configuration:

[image: junit]

The build path configuration:

[image: build path]

The pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.xxx.pipeline</groupId>
  <artifactId>pipeline</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.6.0</exec-maven-plugin.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
    <beam.version>2.16.0</beam.version>
    <apache-commons.version>2.5.0</apache-commons.version>
    <commons-cli.version>1.4</commons-cli.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>ossrh.snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype OSS Repository Hosting</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-protobuf</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>${apache-commons.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-cli.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I looked through the links you included. Have you tried following the instructions in Comment #8 in [the Hamcrest bug](https://code.google.com/archive/p/hamcrest/issues/128)? It says that having maven dependencies and Eclipse's JUnit 4 in the same dependency list causes issues, and they fixed it by removing JUnit 4 from that list and importing it through the maven pom instead.

Comment: Yeah. If I do that, the test run without any problem. I will put that as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I removed the JUnit library which I installed through maven (Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> JUnit -> Junit 3/4/5)

After that, in the pom file I added the Junit dependency (also de hamcrest which I added previously):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
<artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

I delete this line from the dependency `<scope>test</scope>`

After that, I can run the Junit test in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `hamcrest` library in the build.gradle or pom.xml as per your build requirement.
The following piece of code,

```
PAssert.that(input).containsInAnyOrder(COUNTS_ARRAY)
```

the input `pcollection` has only one element with value as `"This is just a message"`  & the `COUNTS_ARRAY` is a list with value as `"This"`.

Since this doesn't match, it is giving an **Assertion error**.

Make the `COUNTS_ARRAY` value to one passed in `pcollection` & your code will work fine.