# Java Security Exception using RestAssured post calls

Tags: java, maven, rest-assured, hamcrest, securityexception

I am getting an exception while using post call using RestAssured.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.hamcrest.Matchers"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:891)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:661)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:754)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:134)
at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:89)
at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.super$2$statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy:142)
at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy)
```

I am using below dependencies in my pom.xml file

cucumber-java 4.8.0
cucumber-junit 4.8.0
io.rest-assured 4.1.2
jackson-databind 2.10.1
commons-io 2.6

i am using below code to call API

```
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream( new File("jsonFileInput\\pricingAPI.json"));
    RestAssured.baseURI ="my base url here";
    
    given().header("Content-Type","application/json")
    .and()
    .body(IOUtils.toString(fileInputStream,"UTF-8"))
    .when()
    .post("v/pr")
    .then()
    .statusCode(200)
    .and()
    .log().all();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow

[hamcrest tests always fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651784/hamcrest-tests-always-fail)

https://code.google.com/archive/p/hamcrest/issues/128

Consolidating the solution - Change the order of the jars on the java build path - you will find that the JUnit jar is above the hamcrest.jar. You can move hamcrest above the JUnit jar here and the problem will go away.