# Servlet under Apache tomcat + eclipselink

Tags: java, servlets, eclipselink

I deployed war to apache. All added eclipselink.jar to \lib folder , and when I try to call servlet :

java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.persistence.spi.ProviderUtil"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

occured

I have read that is some eclipselink bug. But I haven't found solution. I need to use eclipselink.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this thread on Stackoverflow?
[Java SecurityException: signer information does not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match)

It seems that the error you are encountering is due to a conflict or lack of JAR certificates in your library JAR files.