# SecurityException in Java method SecureClassLoader.defineClass()

Tags: java, security, exception, securityexception

The [Javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/security/SecureClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20java.security.CodeSource%29) for this method includes:

> Throws: [SecurityException](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityException.html) - if an attempt is made to add this class to a package
>   that contains classes that were signed by a different set of certificates than
>   this class, or if the class name begins with "java.".

I am getting this exception in my code (the exception does not have anything telling why), and this documentation makes me confused.

**EDIT:** None of the jars I use are signed.

*Can anyone explain this to me, with an example if possible?*

Answer (score 0):

It says that classes from the same package are loaded by different class loaders that are signed by different certificates( or might be an invalid certificate). If you could paste your code snippet for more details it would help. You can find a similar discussion here [Java SecurityException: signer information does not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match)
have a look.