# class "client"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: signer

I've spent 2 days trying to fix this, can't find a fix for this or atleast a solution:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: class "client"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at Loader.main(Loader.java:36)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    client game = new client();
    Loader loader = new Loader();
    game.setStub(loader);
    game.init();
    game.start();
    loader.add(game);
    loader.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    loader.setSize(773, 531);
    loader.setResizable(false);
    loader.setVisible(true); 
}
```

Picture of my libs:
http://puu.sh/28cAP

Dl of my lib:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17359665/lib.jar

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned here, ( [Java SecurityException: signer information does not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match) ) this is related to two jars with the same class having a different signature.  Check your build path libraries and open up the libraries, maybe you spot a library that is either in there twice with different parents or also included in your own jar.  I had this problem with hamcrest version 1.1 being a dependency of JUnit 4 on the build path, and imported by maven, with different signatures.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Maven, I solved it removing the libraries and downloading it again.