# Spring MVC: Not able to use use validator, getting "Injection of autowired dependencies failed"

Tags: java, exception, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

i am creating a simple application with validator, but i am getting below `Exception`:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.validation.Validator mypack.MyController.validator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.validation.Validator mypack.MyController.validator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:838)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:780)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<clinit>(ConfigurationImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:43)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.slf4j.Logger"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2733)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.validator.util.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.validator.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:30)
    ... 46 more
```

Below is my User.java:

```
package mypack;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
public class User {
    @NotEmpty(message = "Username must not be blank.")
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Password must not be blank.")
    @Size(min=8,max=10 , message = "Password must between 8 to 10 Characters.")
    private String pwd;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }
    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }
}
```

Controller class(MyController.java):

```
package mypack;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register.htm")
public class MyController {
    @Autowired  
    public Validator validator;
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator;
    }
    public void setValidator(Validator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
        binder.setValidator(validator);
    }
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(ModelMap m){
        User user=new User();
        m.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "/register.jsp";
    }
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String onSubmit(@Valid User user,BindingResult result){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "/register.jsp";
        }
        //call to service layer to do login validation..
        return "/success.jsp";
    }
}
```

Web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>FormDemo</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

configuration file(dispatcher-servlet.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="mypack" />        
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

</beans>
```

Earlier i was getting following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.validation.Validator mypack.MyController.validator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger

so, i added "slf4j.jar". 
Then i got following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.validation.Validator mypack.MyController.validator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException

then, added "logback-classic-0.9.jar" and "logback-core-0.9.6.jar". So, finally i am stuck with the error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.validation.Validator mypack.MyController.validator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Please help me!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match

Comment: Have you added `hibernate-validator.jar`? Download [here](http://hibernate.org/validator/downloads/) if not

Answer (score 1):

You can remove both the "logback-classic-0.9.jar" and "logback-core-0.9.6.jar" and add the logback.jar. It will work.