# Exception in java.lang.securityexception

Tags: java

I am getting this exception when i am trying to run a simple class from intellijIdea using spark

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.SessionTrackingMode"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:952)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:666)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:794)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at spark.webserver.SparkServerFactory.create(SparkServerFactory.java:33)
    at spark.Spark$1.run(Spark.java:303)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: The message is clear enough: there is a signing problem in the jar you use. How was it produced?

Comment: Does this answer your question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match

Comment: I added a dependency in pom.xml file from sparkjava website