# Error: java.lang.SecurityException: signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I am using below jar files

```
bcmail-jdk16-1.46,
bcprov-jdk16-1.46,
commons-codec-1.9,
commons-io-2.5
```

I am getting error at this line

```
CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(Base64.decode(respBytes));
```

> Error:-
>   java.lang.SecurityException: class
>   "org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodable"'s signer information does not
>   match signer information of other classes in the same package

i tried everything but did not find solution of this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386463/java-lang-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match-signer-informatio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signer information does not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878068/signer-information-does-not-match)

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm currently running into the same exact issue.