# Bouncy Castle is not working on Ubuntu server machine using OpenJDK 11 and tomcat 8.5 and 9

Tags: java, bouncycastle

**Error**
`java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessable"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package`

[image: my Lib file]

It is working fine using eclipse but it now working after deployment on linux machine.

Comment: Did you check, that your deployed product doesn't have the wrong libs included? It sounds like a classpath problem.

Comment: Yes I have checked it. The configuration is ok.

Comment: Then it could be that Eclipse loads the jars in a different order than Tomcat does on itself: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2877262/2135838  Also it seems the problem comes up now and then: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56146240/2135838

Comment: It is working fine on eclipse but when i deploy the application on ubuntu server machine it occur the error

Comment: Did you try to deploy the WAR file to your local tomcat as you would do on your Ubuntu server?

Comment: I have download zip file from the link https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi

Comment: @Sascha It was occurring in ubuntu version 18. It is working fine in ubuntu version 20

Comment: That sounds like it was a problem of the combination Ubuntu 18, OpenJDK 11 and Tomcat.

Comment: I have this same error