# Switching Maven Project from JDK 1.7 to JDK 1.8

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have updated Jacoco version in my maven project as `0.7.1.201405082137`
after that i am getting below error.

```
Java SecurityException: signer information does not match for class org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_9dd1198.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.class
```

Comment: Apparently you expect us to visit the homepages of all those projects and report back here what we have learned? So how about the following: *you* visit those pages, make the necessary changes to your project, and report back here with your findings. The last part is optional.

Comment: Check: [Java SecurityException: signer information does not match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match)