# Lifecycle exception while deploying war file in apache tomcat8

Tags: java, tomcat

I am having my application which work in my sserver machines but not in my local machine. While starting apache tomcat 8 server, I do find the error log as below:

```
16-Apr-2015 19:48:32.247 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/DMS]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "com.trilogy.sc.ISCUser"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:952)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:666)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:794)
                at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2452)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:854)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1264)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:127)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:273)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:133)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5095)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
                ... 10 more

16-Apr-2015 19:48:32.277 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\webapps\DMS.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/DMS]]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Could you please provide me some clues to resolve this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2877355/106261

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java SecurityException: signer information does not match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match)