# Getting an error when execute a scheduler(Quartz 2.0) program in Java

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, spring-4

First i make a `Java` program and using `Quartz` `Scheduler` to do the scheduling job with a new schedule, and when go to  `SchedulerFactory` `class`

```
 SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
```

intialization then i get this error please help what i am doing wrong.

> java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.slf4j.Logger"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:944)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:658)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:786)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>       at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.(StdSchedulerFactory.java:274)
>       at com.ezeon.sch.controller.SchedulerController.saveOrUpDateSchedule(SchedulerController.java:445)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java SecurityException: signer information does not match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match)

Comment: Ya related but didn't get satisfactory answer from there @SanKrish

Comment: Could you show you maven dependencies?

Comment: i am not configure maven in project while adding lib from external source