# Tomcat 8 org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtil

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, rhel, rhel6

I have a web application that uses Apache Common IO version 2.4. When I deploy this application on Tomcat 8.0.39 I am getting following error:

```
> [ERROR] - class "org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:898)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:668)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:761)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2558)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1302)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
at com.b.aD.a(Unknown Source)
at com.b.Bm.getDataSet(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:408)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:279)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:252)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:171)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:68)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProducer.process(BeanProducer.java:38)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
```

This issue particularly faced in RHEL Box not in windows

Comment: Here is a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match