# 'class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package' using Itext

Tags: java, spring, maven, pdf, itext

I'm developing a little tool to watermark **PDFs** and it **works for some** PDFs and **crashes for some** others.

I'm using **iText** library and bouncycastle (dependency)

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.49</version>
    </dependency>
```

It **crashes** at this line (the very first line of code):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
```

With the following **stacktrace**:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:727)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:181)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:219)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:207)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:197)
... <from here it points to my code>
```

I've done some **googling** and some people say that possibly the problem is that I have this **bouncycastle lib duplicated** somewhere.

This is inside an **Spring** application build with **Maven**. So, can this really be a library problem?

I'm using **JDK 1.8**.

**What I've tried**:

- Different bouncycastle versions with Maven.
- Different bouncycastle versions (supporting my JDK version) added manually to the project (including iText).

But the behaviour is exactly the same, some PDF **works** (**always**) and some others **don't** (**ever**).

*Have you ever experienced any problem similar to this one using **iText** library?*

*Is the **problem** **at** the PDF **files** that make the code crash **and not in my project**?*

I'm completely stuck here so any help/tip would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The PDFs that always work, are those that don't use encryption in any way. Those that don't work, they require BouncyCastle. The error doesn't say that BouncyCastle is missing, but that you are using jars that are signed with one key, and other jars that either aren't signed (most likely cause) or the are signed with another key. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match

Comment: Sometimes library classes are added to other artifacts.  Thus, probably the duplicate bc packages are in some jar you wouldn't suspect then to be in.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I will investigate further and update when I advance in any of this two directions. Thanks mkl and Bruno.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Thanks** to **Bruno Lowagie** comments and linked question and **mkl** tip I've found the problem.

In my **build path** there **were two org.bouncycastle libs**, one I **added via Maven** (`bcprov-jdk15on.jar`) and **another one used by Pivotal TC Server** (`com.springsource.org.bouncycastle.jce-1.46.0.jar`).

I've **removed** the **Pivotal** TC Server **bouncycastle jar** and the **error has gone away**.

[image: Pivotal bouncycastle jar was there]

Using STS I was unable to remove it, so I found it on the filesystem and moved from the folder Pivotal TC expected it to be. Then, the lib disappeared at STS.

I haven't removed it just in case, only moved to another directory. If I have problems with Pivotal TC from now on I will update my answer.