# xades4j verification issue with embeded x509 certificate

Tags: java, xml-signature, xades4j

I am using smart card for signing and SunMSCAPI provider and windows key store.
Using xades4j 1.3.2 version I am singing an xml file as follows and it is working perfectly and the certificate is also embeded in xml file in KeyInfo,

```
private Document signXMLData(Document doc) {
        try {
            XadesSigningProfile p;
            p = new XadesBesSigningProfile(keyingDataProvider).withSignaturePropertiesProvider(new SignaturePropertiesProvider() {
                @Override
                public void provideProperties(SignaturePropertiesCollector signedPropsCol) {
                    signedPropsCol.setSignerRole(new SignerRoleProperty(SignerRole));
                    signedPropsCol.setSignatureProductionPlace(new SignatureProductionPlaceProperty(City, State, PostalCode, Country));
                    signedPropsCol.setSigningTime(new SigningTimeProperty());
                }
            });
            XadesSigner signer = p.newSigner();
            Element elemToSign = doc.getDocumentElement();
            new Enveloped(signer).sign(elemToSign);
            Log.LogOperation("XML signing completed successfully.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.LogException(ex);
            doc = null;
        }
        return doc;
    }
```

But my problem is, while verifying using following code, I am getting following error,

Code

```
public boolean VerifyXMLSign(String data) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException, Exception {
        InputSource isIn = new InputSource();
        isIn.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(data));

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(isIn);
        //Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream("c:/xml.xml"));
        DOMHelper.useIdAsXmlId(doc.getDocumentElement());

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT", "SunMSCAPI");
        ks.load(null, null);

        X509Certificate x509Certificate = null;
        PublicKey key = null;
        DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(new X509KeySelector(ks), getSigElement(doc));
        XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
        fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null);
        XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);
        KeyInfo keyInfo = signature.getKeyInfo();
        Iterator hKeyInfo = keyInfo.getContent().iterator();
        while (hKeyInfo.hasNext()) {
            XMLStructure hX509Data = (XMLStructure) hKeyInfo.next();
            if (!(hX509Data instanceof X509Data)) {
                continue;
            }
            X509Data x509Data = (X509Data) hX509Data;
            Iterator hX509Certificate = x509Data.getContent().iterator();
            while (hX509Certificate.hasNext()) {
                Object oX509Certificate = hX509Certificate.next();
                if (!(oX509Certificate instanceof X509Certificate)) {
                    continue;
                }
                x509Certificate = ((X509Certificate) oX509Certificate);
                key = x509Certificate.getPublicKey();
            }
        }

        //FileSystemDirectoryCertStore certStore = createDirectoryCertStore("my");
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        ks.setCertificateEntry("df", x509Certificate);

        CertificateValidationProvider validationProviderMySigs = new PKIXCertificateValidationProvider(ks, false, null);//certStore.getStore());
        XadesVerificationProfile instance = new XadesVerificationProfile(validationProviderMySigs);
        XadesVerifier verifier = instance.newVerifier();
        XAdESVerificationResult r = verifier.verify(getSigElement(doc), null);

        System.out.println(r.getSignatureForm());
        System.out.println(r.getSignatureAlgorithmUri());
        System.out.println(r.getSignedDataObjects().size());
        System.out.println(r.getQualifyingProperties().all().size());
        return false;
    }
```

Error

```
Log Date Time:- 2017/06/08 14:38:01
xades4j.utils.XadesProfileResolutionException: com.google.inject.internal.ComputationException: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaX509CertSelectorConverter"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at xades4j.utils.XadesProfileCore.getInstance(XadesProfileCore.java:223)
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerificationProfile.newVerifier(XadesVerificationProfile.java:147)
    at slr.DigitalVerification.VerifyXMLSign(DigitalVerification.java:163)
    at slr.Handlers$OpenEVerifierHandler.handle(Handlers.java:186)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:80)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:677)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$DefaultExecutor.execute(ServerImpl.java:158)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.handle(ServerImpl.java:433)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.run(ServerImpl.java:398)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.ComputationException: ..........
```

I tried the method suggested in https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/issues/37 but that also giving the same error.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error it seems something related to mixing up security providers, probably because you create the `KeyStore` from "SunMSCAPI" and then the `X509Certificate` is created by the provider used on the XML signature, which seems to be bouncy castle.

Anyway, since the signing certificate is included on the signature **you don't need to be parsing the XML and looking for it**. The purpose of *xades4j* is to abstract you away from that stuff. *xades4j* will collect all the certificates in `KeyInfo` and use them to build a chain when validating the signing certificate (in this case there's likely only one).

If all the intermediate certificates and root certificates needed to validate your singing certificate are either on *Windows-ROOT* or within `KeyInfo`, you just need to create the trusted roots `KeyStore` and pass it to `PKIXCertificateValidationProvider` as-is. If you need to include additional certificates, you can use the `CertStore` parameter of `PKIXCertificateValidationProvider` constructor.

So, to sum up, all the code you should need is the first and last parts. Something like:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(isIn);
DOMHelper.useIdAsXmlId(doc.getDocumentElement());

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT", "SunMSCAPI");
ks.load(null, null);
CertificateValidationProvider validationProviderMySigs = new PKIXCertificateValidationProvider(ks, false, null);
XadesVerificationProfile instance = new XadesVerificationProfile(validationProviderMySigs);
XadesVerifier verifier = instance.newVerifier();
XAdESVerificationResult r = verifier.verify(getSigElement(doc), null);
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comment. I tried all above possibilities. the X509Certificate is created by BC. I tried keystore values BKS, JKS and imported certificates using the code in my question. But in all cases same error is coming on line XadesVerifier verifier = instance.newVerifier();. I tried above code also, but that also throwing same error. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: What if you don't supply a provider on the `KeyStore.getInstance()` call?

Comment: If you mean with KeyStore.DefaultProvider() it is giving same error. getinstance is expecting some value.

Comment: I mean the [overload without the provider parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)), which should return the first provider that supports the supplied type. If this doesn't work, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Oh sorry, this way also same result, KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT");

Comment: Can you create a GIST with the full validation code you're using now?

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with xades4j. Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match). Are you including Bouncycastle on your application directly? because xades4j may be pulling a different version or something like that.