# bug:java.lang.SecurityExceptionsigner information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: java

Bouncycastle encryption error
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECCurve$AbstractFp"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Comment: ...and what is your question? What did you do to get this Exception?

Comment: I use bouncycastle encryption, the local test can pass, the server will report this exception, how to solve this exception?I found other solutions, but I can't.

Comment: Introduced bcpkix-jdk15on-1.60.jar and bcprov-jdk15on-1.60.jar these two packages, the local can be, the server will report an error, why?

Comment: Is anybody here?

Comment: related question, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match

Comment: i.e. the easiest thing to try is to swap the order of the jars

Comment: Sorry,but how to swap the order of the jars?

Comment: Because it is different from the encryption that comes with jdk, it need to configure it under the secutity of jdk?

Comment: That depends on how you build your project. In the linnked question there are answers for maven and eclipse.