# Spring boot + tomcat deployment + illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies Issue

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, jackson, tomcat9, cyclic-dependency

I have created a spring boot application. When i try to deploy my application on tomcat server, the jetty dependency in pom.xml was causing the issue. I removed Jetty dependency and then tried to deploy. Now, I am getting the below error related to illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. I am stuck. 
Please find the below error and pom.

Can you please suggest how to fix it ?

```
<parent>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <tomcat.version>9.0</tomcat.version>
    <start-class>spring-boot-example.Application</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <!--  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>  
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>          
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.10</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>                   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>       
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nulab-inc</groupId>
        <artifactId>zxcvbn</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.groupdocs</groupId>
       <artifactId>groupdocs-signature</artifactId>
       <version>18.8</version>
       <type>jar</type>
   </dependency>    
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.groupdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>groupdocs-annotation</artifactId>
        <version>18.10</version> 
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.20</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>GroupDocsJavaAPI</id>
        <name>GroupDocs Java API</name>
        <url>http://artifact.groupdocs.com/repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CDSTApplication]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/CDSTApplication] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [com.aspose.email.internal.E.d->com.aspose.email.internal.E.f->com.aspose.email.internal.E.d]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2143)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2087)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2033)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:2003)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1956)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1160)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5007)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more



package com.aspose.email.internal.E;

import com.aspose.email.a.b.b;
import com.aspose.email.a.b.c;
import com.aspose.email.a.b.z;
import com.aspose.email.internal.h.j;

    public class d extends f {
        private String b;
        private int c;
        private int d;
        static char[] a;

        public d(String paramString) {
            if (paramString == null) {
                throw new c("s");
            }
            this.b = paramString;
            this.c = 0;
            this.d = paramString.length();
        }

        public void close() {
            dispose(true);
        }

        protected void dispose(boolean paramBoolean) {
            this.b = null;
            super.dispose(paramBoolean);
        }

        public int peek() {
            if (this.b == null) {
                a();
            }
            if (this.c >= this.d) {
                return -1;
            }
            return this.b.charAt(this.c);
        }

        public int read() {
            if (this.b == null) {
                a();
            }
            if (this.c >= this.d) {
                return -1;
            }
            return this.b.charAt(this.c++);
        }

        public int read(char[] paramArrayOfChar, int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
            if (this.b == null) {
                a();
            }
            if (paramArrayOfChar == null) {
                throw new c("buffer");
            }
            if (paramArrayOfChar.length - paramInt1 < paramInt2) {
                throw new b();
            }
            if ((paramInt1 < 0) || (paramInt2 < 0)) {
                throw new com.aspose.email.a.b.d();
            }
            int i;
            if (this.c > this.d - paramInt2) {
                i = this.d - this.c;
            } else {
                i = paramInt2;
            }
            j.a(this.b, this.c, paramArrayOfChar, paramInt1, i);
            this.c += i;
            return i;
        }

        public String readLine() {
            if (this.b == null) {
                a();
            }
            if (this.c >= this.b.length()) {
                return null;
            }
            if (a == null) {
                a = new char[] { '\n', '\r' };
            }
            int i = j.a(this.b, a, this.c);
            if (i == -1) {
                return readToEnd();
            }
            int j = (this.b.charAt(i) == '\r') && (i + 1 < this.b.length()) && (this.b.charAt(i + 1) == '\n') ? 1 : 0;
            String str = j.b(this.b, this.c, i - this.c);
            this.c = (i + (j != 0 ? 2 : 1));
            return str;
        }

        public String readToEnd() {
            if (this.b == null) {
                a();
            }
            String str = j.b(this.b, this.c, this.d - this.c);
            this.c = this.d;
            return str;
        }

        static void a() {
            throw new z("StringReader", "Cannot read from a closed StringReader");
        }
    }



package com.aspose.email.internal.E;

import com.aspose.email.internal.a.t;
import com.aspose.email.internal.h.G;

public abstract class f implements com.aspose.email.a.j {
    public static f uD = new a();

    public void close() {
        dispose(true);
    }

    public void dispose() {
        dispose(true);
    }

    protected void dispose(boolean paramBoolean) {
        if (paramBoolean) {
            G.a(this);
        }
    }

    public int peek() {
        return -1;
    }

    public int read() {
        return -1;
    }

    public int read(char[] paramArrayOfChar, int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < paramInt2; i++) {
            int j;
            if ((j = read()) == -1) {
                return i;
            }
            paramArrayOfChar[(paramInt1 + i)] = ((char) j);
        }
        return i;
    }

    public String readLine() {
        t localt = new t();
        int i;
        while (((i = read()) != -1) && (i != 10)) {
            if (i == 13) {
                if (peek() != 10) {
                    break;
                }
                read();
                break;
            }
            localt.w((char) i);
        }
        if ((i == -1) && (localt.b() == 0)) {
            return null;
        }
        return localt.toString();
    }

    public String readToEnd() {
        t localt = new t();
        int i;
        while ((i = read()) != -1) {
            localt.w((char) i);
        }
        return localt.toString();
    }

    static final class a extends f {
        public String readLine() {
            return null;
        }

        public String readToEnd() {
            return com.aspose.email.internal.h.j.a;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java SecurityException: signer information does not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update .  I was able to resolve those dependencies by excluding few jars. Now, I am stuck with another issue related to cyclic dependency. I am unable to resolve it. I have updated the error logs. Can you please advise ?

Comment: Could you show these problematic classes: `com.aspose.email.internal.E.d` and `com.aspose.email.internal.E.f`?

Comment: Hi, I have added those 2 classes below error logs. Can you please check ?