# new FirebaseOptions.Build() throws SecurityException

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, glassfish, firebase-admin

I've tried to use Firebase with Glassfish, but when I try to create a `new Firebae.Build()` it throws an SecurityException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.slf4j.Logger"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:898)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:668)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:761)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:801)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.FirebaseThreadManagers.<clinit>(FirebaseThreadManagers.java:34)
    ... 33 more
```

Basically:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder.<init>(FirebaseOptions.java:235)
```

But i don't see any problem in the code, it's basically the same as in the Google web:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("xxxxxx.json")))
                        .setDatabaseUrl("https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/")
                        .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

I had to install every .jar by hand, that's a list of them (I've read it may be a compatibility error, but I didn't found any).

- firebase-admin-6.8.1.jar
- google-api-client-1.25.0.jar
- google-auth-library-credentials-0.15.0.jar
- google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.15.0.jar
- google-cloud-storage-1.73.0.jar
- google-http-client-1.20.0.jar
- google-http-client-gson-1.20.0.jar
- google-http-client-jackson2-1.27.0.jar
- google-oauth-client-1.25.0.jar
- gson-2.1.jar
- guava-27.1-jre.jar
- json.jar
- logback-classic-0.9.jar
- logback-core-0.9.6.jar
- slf4j.jar

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really the best place for bug reports.  Please post your issue on the Firebase admin GitHub. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java

Comment: Check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2877355/2408342