# SecurityException from conflicting Cordapp classes in a signed jar

Tags: corda

When deploying a Cordapp to a web server the following error was received:

`Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "<com.foo.objects>.Node"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package"`

1. Why are Cordapp jars conflicting with my other web server dependencies?
2. How did the Cordapp jars get signed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background on the original error is here: [Java SecurityException: signer information does not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match)

The Cordapp jars will conflict if they or one of their dependencies shares the same class name as one of your existing dependencies. In this case a `Node` class within a Cordapp dependency is conflicting with another web server dependency.

Cordapp jars are signed by default with the Corda development certificate. You can disable this by setting the cordapp signing `enabled` option to false: https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-build-systems.html#signing-the-cordapp-jar