# Getting java.lang.SecurityException - "org.hamcrest.Matchers"'s signer information does not match

Tags: java, rest-assured, hamcrest, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am executing below Rest Assured Program:

```
        io.restassured.RestAssured.baseURI ="http://a.b.c.d:9200/e/f";
        Response responseNew=null;
        request = RestAssured.given();

        JSONObject requestparams = new JSONObject();
        //Setting params
        requestparams.put("field", "1");
        request.body(requestparams.toJSONString());
        
        //Submitting Request
        responseNew= request.when().contentType(ContentType.JSON).accept(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(inputObject).when().post("/path");
        
        //Status Code Check
        responseNew.then().assertThat().statusCode(200);
```

I am getting below Error at the line where Status code is verified,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.hamcrest.Matchers"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003862/7574461

Comment: Hi , After doing this, Exception is thrown for line "responseNew.then().assertThat().statusCode(200);"          java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List
 at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.getList(JsonPath.java:375)
 at com.AllFunctions.Counts_RestAssured.RegistrationSuccessful(Counts_RestAssured.java:145)

Comment: This error means you're try to extract data from response body with wrong path. `responseNew.then().assertThat().statusCode(200)` doesn't extract anything from response body. Please add more info to your question. full stack trace, response body and full code.

Comment: Hi , Below is the code,
io.restassured.RestAssured.baseURI ="http://a.b.c.d:9200/e/f";
Response responseNew=null;
request = RestAssured.given();  
JSONObject requestparams = new JSONObject();
requestparams.put("parameter", "1");
request.body(requestparams.toJSONString());
 responseNew= request.when().contentType(ContentType.JSON).accept(ContentType.JSON)
.body(inputObject).when().post("/_search");
responseNew.then().assertThat().statusCode(200);
JsonPath extractor = responseNew.jsonPath();
List<String> valid_rec_1= extractor.getList("field_name");

Comment: Please update your question, I cannot read code in comment. Thanks

Comment: Hi , Can you pl give me your email address?I will send the code.Not able to fit in .

Comment: It's better if we can solve the problem here, in Stackoverflow. I think the problem is `List<String> valid_rec_1= extractor.getList("field_name");` You just need to edit your question, add sample response and actual `field_name`, then I can figure it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17565202/3190953

Comment: field Name:unique_id , Datatype:String  , Response : io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@8692d67

Comment: Now getting Null Pointer Exception at Line :   List<String> valid_rec_1= extractor.getList("field_name");

Comment: @AbhishekRao If the issue with `Hamcrest verion` is solved, then close this question and open new question for new issue. *PLEASE*, add enough detail to your question.