# Eliminating SecurityException with saxon jar in Gradle 8

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, saxon, securityexception

I have a Gradle 8 Java program that is throwing this exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "net.sf.saxon.value.UntypedAtomicValue"'s signer
information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

The class `net.sf.saxon.value.UntypedAtomicValue` appears to be part of [Saxon-HE](https://javadoc.io/static/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/9.8.0-7/net/sf/saxon/value/UntypedAtomicValue.html).

An answer to [Java SecurityException: signer information does not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match) says:

> This happens when classes belonging to the same package are loaded from different JAR files, and those JAR files have signatures signed with different certificates - or, perhaps more often, at least one is signed and one or more others are not (which includes classes loaded from directories since those AFAIK cannot be signed).
> Another response indicates that it can be due to a duplicated jar.

These are the dependencies for my project:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.javaparser:javaparser-symbol-solver-core:3.25.3'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    implementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.10.0-M1'
    implementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console:1.10.0-RC1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.10.0-M1'
    implementation 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.10'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20230618'
    implementation 'com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:10.12.1'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd:6.54.0'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-java:6.54.0'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-core:6.54.0'
}
```

To find transitive dependencies, I ran:

```
./gradlew dependencies > dependencies.txt
```

Here is an excerpt of the results:

```
+--- com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:10.12.1
|    +--- info.picocli:picocli:4.7.4
|    +--- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.11.1
|    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4
|    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:32.0.1-jre (*)
|    +--- org.reflections:reflections:0.10.2
|    |    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.28.0-GA -> 3.29.2-GA
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32
|    +--- net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:12.2                          <-----
|    |    \--- org.xmlresolver:xmlresolver:5.1.2
|    \--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:3.27.0 -> 3.33.0
+--- net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd:6.54.0
+--- net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-java:6.54.0
|    +--- net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-core:6.54.0
|    |    +--- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.7.2 -> 4.11.1
|    |    +--- com.beust:jcommander:1.48
|    |    +--- net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon:9.1.0.8            <-----
|    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.3 -> 9.5
|    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9
|    +--- net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon:9.1.0.8                 <-----
|    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.3 -> 9.5
|    \--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1
+--- net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-core:6.54.0 (*)
```

The artifact `net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE` appears only once (for `checkstyle`). The presumably related artifact `net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon` appears multiple times under `net.sourceforge.pmd` artifacts, always the same version: 9.1.0.8. (This is the only available version of [`saxon`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.saxon/saxon).)

The `SecurityException` goes away if I remove the `checkstyle` dependency, so it may be some sort of conflict between `net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE`.

I got a library conflict when I tried using a PMD 7 RC. Although Gradle doesn't show a dependency from checkstyle to PMD, one appears in checkstyle's [pom.xml](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/pom.xml).

My questions are:

1. Why I am getting this error?
2. How can I fix it in this Gradle 8 (Groovy DSL) project?

Comment: Are there any up to date versions of the pmd packages that might use Saxon 12, like the checkstyle project?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Good question. Unfortunately, PMD 7.0 depends on `Saxon-HE:10.7`, while the latest version of checkstyle depends on `Saxon-HE:12.2`.

Comment: If there is a combination of pdm and checkstyle versions that uses the same Saxon main version (e.g. 10) then I would try the combination to rule out that the error is simply caused by having two versions of Saxon on the class path.

Comment: It looks very much to me as if you have two different versions of Saxon on the classpath, which isn't going to work.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you. Are you saying that `net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon` and `net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE` can't co-exist?

Comment: Correct. They are different versions of the same product, they contain identically-named classes, and that's going to confuse the ClassLoader.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelKay. Do you want to give this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the failure is because you have two different versions of Saxon on the classpath. This isn't going to work, because the class loader will load classes from the two different versions more or less at random, and they won't be compatible with each other.

There's no easy solution. You're going to have to upgrade all parts of the application to use the same Saxon version. If some of those components are third-party code, and if they dig deep into Saxon internal interfaces rather than sticking to the stable public API, then this may not be a trivial task.